# Getting row data from Database to JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Im trying to display the data from a Databse using joins. I manage to display the first table but I get a null exception error when trying to display the other data. Im doing this via the Java Class.

Here is the function...

```
public List<administration> fullList() throws Exception{

    List<administration> result = new ArrayList<administration>();

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connectMe = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, userNameDB, passwordDB);

        String query = "SELECT  \n" + 
                " ControlAccess.UserName, \n" +
                " ControlAccess.Pass, \n" +
                " Users.First_Name,\n" +
                " Users.Last_Name, \n" +
                " UserInfo.Age, \n" +
                " UserInfo.Country,\n" +
                " UserInfo.Address,\n" +
                " UserInfo.ZipCode,\n" +
                " Sessions.Matrix1,\n" +
                " Sessions.Matrix2,\n" +
                " Sessions.Result,\n" +
                " FilePath.LocationFiles\n" +
                " FROM MatrixUsers.UserInfo \n" +
                " INNER JOIN MatrixUsers.Users\n" +
                " ON UserInfo.idUserInfo = Users.idUsers\n" +
                " INNER JOIN MatrixUsers.ControlAccess \n" +
                " ON ControlAccess.idControlAccess = UserInfo.idUserInfo\n" +
                " INNER JOIN MatrixUsers.Sessions \n" +
                " ON Sessions.idSessions = ControlAccess.idControlAccess\n" +
                " INNER JOIN MatrixUsers.FilePath \n" +
                " ON FilePath.idFilePath = Sessions.idSessions";

        selectUsers = connectMe.prepareStatement(query);
        results = selectUsers.executeQuery();

        while(results.next()) {

            administration admin = new administration();

            admin.setUserName(results.getString("UserName"));
            admin.setPassword(results.getString("Pass"));
            admin.setFirstname(results.getString("First_Name"));
            admin.setLastname(results.getString("Last_Name"));
            admin.setAge(results.getInt("Age"));
            admin.setCountry(results.getString("Country"));
            admin.setAddress(results.getString("Address"));
            admin.setZipcode(results.getInt("ZipCode"));
            admin.setMatrix1(results.getString("Matrix1"));
            admin.setMatrix2(results.getString("Matrix2"));
            admin.setResult(results.getString("Result"));
            admin.setLocation(results.getString("LocationFiles"));
            result.add(admin);

        }

       results.close();
       connectMe.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is the sets and gets:

```
 public String getUsername() {
    return username;    
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public int getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}

public String getMatrix1() {
    return Matrix1;
}

public String getMatrix2() {
    return Matrix2;
}

public String getResult() {
    return Result;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public int getID() {
    return id;
}

public void setUserName(String aUser) {
    username = aUser;
}

public void setPassword(String aPass) {
    password = aPass;
}

public void setFirstname(String aFirstname) {
    firstName = aFirstname;
}

public void setLastname(String aLastname) {
    lastName = aLastname;
}

public void setAge(int anAge) {
    age = anAge;
}

public void setCountry(String aCountry) {
    country = aCountry;
}

public void setAddress(String anAddress) {
    address = anAddress; 
}

public void setZipcode(int aZipcode) {
    zipcode = aZipcode;
}

public void setMatrix1(String aMatrix) {
    Matrix1 = aMatrix;
}

public void setMatrix2(String aMatrix) {
    Matrix2 = aMatrix;
}

public void setResult(String aResult) {
    Result = aResult;
}

public void setLocation(String aLocation) {
    location = aLocation;
}
```

I display using iteration in the JSP. Any extra info you need just ask! I'll be looking to see if I can find the error myself. Also I apologize for the huge query statement, its part of a assignment and its  requisite.

JSP code:

```
<table>
        <c:forEach var="admin" items="${result}">
            <tr>

                <td><c:out value = "${admin.username}" /> </td>
                <td>${admin.password} </td>
                <td>${admin.firstName} </td>
                <td>${admin.lastName} </td>
                <td>${admin.age} </td>
                <td>${admin.country} </td>
                <td>${admin.address} </td>
                <td>${admin.zipcode} </td>
                <td>${admin.Matrix1} </td>
                <td>${admin.Matrix2} </td>
                <td>${admin.Result} </td>
                <td>${admin.location} </td>
            </tr>


        </c:forEach>

    </table>
```

The stack error is:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'firstName' not found on type matrixcalculator.administration
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:229)
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:206)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:317)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:182)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:967)
org.apache.jsp.showFullList_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(showFullList_jsp.java:149)
org.apache.jsp.showFullList_jsp._jspService(showFullList_jsp.java:98)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
org.apache.jsp.processInfo_jsp._jspService(processInfo_jsp.java:88)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

-Silvestrini

Comment: Please tell us from which line the null pointer exception came from..

Comment: @ Ollie Jones the problem starts when trying to display the firstName. Note this is on the JSP that happens. I get the username and password but from firstName and down I get the null pointer exception. I'll edit the code to show the JSP. EDITED TO SHOW JSP

Comment: @Silvestrini When you ask about an exception, ALWAYS post the complete stack trace of the exception. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @ JB Nizet by the complete stack trace you mean the error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: I had a clue it was that, I posted the stack trace!

Answer (score 1):

The exception message is very clear:

> Property 'firstName' not found on type matrixcalculator.administration

That means there is no method with the following signature in the class `matrixcalculator.administration`:

```
public String getFirstName()
```

Comment: I do have all the gets and sets methods for every attribute declared in my class. Do you mean I have to call it explicitly?

Comment: No, I mean you don't have it. Where is the code to prove it? Post it in your question.

Comment: Yes. And indeed, you don't have it. The case matters: your method is named `getFirstname`. And you're accessing the property `firstName`. `n != N`.

Comment: I edited and now I get same error at Matrix1. :S I dont see the difference there...

Comment: Once again. If the getter is `getMatrix1()`, then the property name is `matrix1`, not `Matrix1`. if the getter is `getFooBarBaz()`, the property is `fooBarBaz`. Properties always start with a lowercase letter, just as Java variables.

Comment: Just to be clear, the word that follows the "get" must ALWAYS be lower case?

Comment: NOOOO. Read my comments correctly. I said: if your getter is named `getFooBarBaz()`, then the corresponding property name, used in the JSP EL expressions, is `fooBarBaz`. The first letter after `get` is uppercase. The first letter of the property is lowercase. property `fooBarBaz` <==> getter `getFooBarBaz()`.

Comment: Ohhh hahaha okay I get it now. Property first letter ALWAYS lowercase so JSP knows what it is. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'firstName' not found on
>   type matrixcalculator.administration

That just means that the given class doesn't have the following method:

```
public SomeObject getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
```

if this method is present then make sure signature is exactly the same it should be `public` and take `no arguments`

**Update**

Problem is Your getterName is not in [camelCase](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) whereas your variable name is in camelCase

> ```
> public String getFirstname() {
>     return firstName;
> }
> ```

change it to

```
public String getFirstName() {  // N should be capital
    return firstName;
}
```

Comment: Edited the question, posted all the sets and gets!

Comment: you are using `getFirstname`  it should be `getFirstName`

Comment: Ahhhh I see it must be literally the same as the DataBase column names? Now I get the same error at Matrix1?

Comment: @Silvestrini the database column name is irrelevant. Your JSP is getting data from a Java Bean. Not from the database. What matters is the Java Beans conventions.

Comment: @Silvestrini    you should keep you variable name as matrix1 and in jsp use
${admin.matrix1} , i suugest you to please read that link i have provided in my answer

Comment: Variable names first letter always lowercase?

Comment: Thank you so much for fixing this and also providing the link.